# Populating query with widget results Python 3x tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-datetime

I am still trying to populate a query with the results of a calendar widget I created. The calendar widget works perfectly and the weeklyrpt.py works perfectly if the message box is answered with a yes response. A no response opens the calendar widget where dates are picked and parsed out individually but I cannot figure out how to integrate the results into my query.

The rundate function is

```
def rundate():
    global run
    result = tkinter.messagebox.askyesno(title="Rundate", message="back 7 days?")
#result = tkinter.messagebox.askyesno()
    if result == True:
        run = date.today() - timedelta(7)
        return run
    if result == False:
        os.system("python pick.py") 

#opens the pick.py program which is a calendar the after choosing the dates returns this function

def get_rundate():
        start = self.result1.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
        end = self.result2.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") 
        daterange = pd.date_range(start, end)
        for single_date in daterange:
            print(single_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"))             
        return single_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")

#then returns to weeklyreport

rundate = rundate()
print(rundate)
```

The data I am trying to obtain for the query is the "rundate"

```
#Query permits made effective since rundate

query = '''select `NPDES_ID`, `EffectiveDate`, `FacilityName`, `StateFacilityID`, `City`, `CountyName`
        from Permits 
        where `EffectiveDate` >= ?
        order by `NPDES_ID`'''

#for each row in result of query
for row in cur.execute(query, (rundate)):
try:
    d= row[1].strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
except:
    d=""

for i in range(len(row)):
    if not row[i]:
        row[i] = ""
```

I need help getting the results from the pick.py widget to return as rundate within weeklyrpt.py. As I said the first part of the rundate function works fine (returns the data request going back 7 days)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the only problem, but definitely *a* problem is this:

```
for row in cur.execute(query, (rundate)):
```

`(rundate)` is a single value, `(rundate,)` is a tuple. `cur.execute` requires a tuple.

Comment: Any hints as to how would I fix that? I am new to all this

Comment: @pja: my hint is in the answer. Use `(rundate,)` where you currently have `(rundate)`.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense

Comment: evidently that is not my only problem...I am getting "none" for the rundate when I use the calendar so I am not correctly calling the results of pick.py. Do you know how do I get the results from there?